# Не удается преобразовать из "SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image" в "string". Для дискорд бота

Tags: c#, изображения, discord-api

хочу вывести свое изображение на дискорд канал с помощью бота решил воспользоваться фреймворком "Imagesharp" вроде код с выводом изображения правильно из документации взял но не могу вывести на дискорд канал, попробовал записать string a = $"{zx}" await ReplyAsync(a) и все равно не сработало.  библиотека для бота discord.net

```
        int Width = 640;
        int Height = 480;

        [Command("cmd")]
        public async Task TestCmd()
        {
            

            var zx = Image.Load("Images/1ub.jpg");
            {
                
                zx.Mutate(x => x.Resize(zx.Width / 2, zx.Height / 2));

                zx.Save("Images/1ub.jpg");
              
            }

            string a = $"{zx}";
           

            await ReplyAsync(zx);
        }
```

Comment: А какой смысл в этой вашей библиотеке? На сколько мне известно, отправка во всяких популярных фреймворках делается простым `channel.SendFileAsync("путь", "подпись")` и мне вот не понятно, зачем вы используете эту библиотеку, что бы что? Изменить размер? Странное тогда решение... Ищите тогда там же, где и `SendFileAsync` отправку потока или байтов.

Comment: [Вот что нашел](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51010769/12888024)

Comment: @aepot в примере который вы мне скинули это делается через embedbuilder а мне не нужно чтобы у меня картинка была в embed сообщении

Comment: Тогда первый комментарий для вас. Ну или вот [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50298378/12888024)